# Mean reverting process with observation

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, kalman-filter

I've developed an indicator that is very highly correlated to a the value of a related basket of time series. When I regress over the indicators and values at different points in the time series the $R^2$ is always very high. Below is a graph of scaled values of the time series vs the value of the indicator for each firm at that point in time. The application of this model is intended to be the valuation of securities on the stock maret.

[image]

The calculation of the indicator, on the x axis, is not in any way dependent on the value of the y axis. The correlation holds over the entirety of the time series; the $R^2$ of the relationship remains >= ~95% at every point in time. The points also appear to regress towards the line. This is where the indicator of motion comes from. Basically, for a specific industry, I believe I have developed an indicator that is highly correlated to the market value of these companies and that their market value reverts towards the 'mean' of the regression line.

I'm attempting to use this distance from the line as my upside indicator for stock trading. When I do a walk-forward test and calculate daily upside signals from this regression line for each company and compare to the percentage change in the real value of the security following day, the p value of the Pearson correlation is extremely low.

However, the $R^2$ of the first order regression between the signal and realized value is low and the p value is high; does this mean that the correlation is non-linear? As an auxiliary question, is this an appropriate test of the signal? I believe that this is testing the predicative ability of the model.

Given these parameters, what would be the best area of time series models to research? I have looked into autoregressive models, such as ARIMAX, as well as state-space models, like UKF's, but I'm not sure what would be the best area to test and read up more on.